# If class other than my class is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I have a dynamic list that looks something like this

```
<li>item 1</li>
<ii>item 2</li>
<ii class="route2">item 2</li>
<ii>item 3</li>
<ii>item 4</li>
```

and two buttons

```
<button>Route one</button>
<button>Route two</button>
```

I can't work how to show the route two button only if all list items have the route2 class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
if ( $('li').not('.route2').length ){
    $('button').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One possible way:

```
$("button:eq(1)").toggle( !$("li:not(.route2)").length );
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/CNP7Z/